# Using jQuery with Visual Studio SPA template

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, typescript, vue.js

I've created a project using the Visual Studio SPA template. This project is using ASP.NET Core template, Vue.js and Webpack. I'm having issues using `jQuery` within the project.

Within the `package.json` file, it has

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "vue": "^2.2.2",
    "vue-loader": "^11.1.4",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^5.0.1",
    "vue-router": "^2.3.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.2.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2"
  }
```

And within the `ProjectName.Web.csproj`:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="jQuery" Version="3.2.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

When I attempt it import `jQuery` into a `TypeScript` file using:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

I get the error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'jquery'. {project path}/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

What setting am I missing in order to use `jQuery`? Also I would like to confirm that the lines in the `package.json` and `ProjectName.Web.csproj` files do in face install `jQuery` within the project.

Answer (score 1):

I finally was able to get jQuery working in my project.

I updated my code using the example [here](https://github.com/Jbelles/JarretBellesSPA/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=jquery&type=)

I also needed to run `npm install @types/jquery` for my project.

After those two steps and using the `import * as $ from 'jquery';` statement, I received the error:

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:2961:63 
>       TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.`

With searching online, I found that changing

```
"target": "es5"
```

to

```
"target": "es6"
```

Within the `tsconfig.json` file removed the error.